# Send email button in custom post type backend

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, forms, email, wp-mail

I've added a button in the backend of my custom post type editor.

I want to send an email using `wp_mail()` when admin user click a button.

I've added this custom form and button to a meta box. See screenshot.

The problem is that when clicking this button Wordpress redirects to the default backend posts list page (https://mysite.test/wp-admin/edit.php).

I am making use of the `do_action( "admin_post_{$action}" )` hook.

When I inspect the page I see Wordpress has removed the  tags.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $quote_add_meta_nonce = wp_create_nonce('send_quote_email_form_nonce');

    add_action('admin_post_quote_email_pdf', 'quote_email_pdf');

    function quote_email_pdf()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['send_quote_email_meta_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['send_quote_email_meta_nonce'], 'send_quote_email_form_nonce')) {
            $emailMessage = '<h1>It works</h1>';
            echo $emailMessage;
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong';
        }
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="quote_email_pdf">
    <input type="hidden" name="send_quote_email_meta_nonce" value="<?php echo $quote_add_meta_nonce ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Email quote to customer" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you want to stay on the same page after the submit? So why not send the form via an Ajax call?

Comment: I have posted this on Stackoverflow as well. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71583212/send-email-button-in-custom-post-type-backend/71585526#71585526

I have indeed solved this using AJAX.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you have found a solution. Please do not forget to accept the answer. [Accept your own answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using AJAX. Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_quote_email_pdf', 'quote_email_pdf');

function quote_email_pdf()
{
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

    die();
}
?>
<button class="button" id="downloadQuote">Send email</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  const fullName = $('#quoteFullName').text();
  const emailAddress = $('#quoteEmail a').text();

  $('#downloadQuote').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: sf_admin_ajax.sf_admin_ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          action: 'quote_email_pdf',
          emailAddress: emailAddress,
          fullName: fullName
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
          $('.preloader-window').addClass('active')
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
          $('.preloader-window').removeClass('active')
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function ( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
          $('.preloader-window').removeClass('active')
          console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    })

  })
});
</script>
```